# bounce castle aes encryption in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

can you please any one explain AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption and decryption using bounce

castle i tried hardly myself but i am not getting any success.

on net i am not getting tutorial regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking about the Bouncy Castle lightweight API that is part of the J2ME release. From the [specifications page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html), there is an example of how to use the API. I've updated it to match the latest API. (Note that I haven't tried to run this.)

```
BlockCipher engine = new AESEngine();
BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(engine));

byte[] key = keyString.getBytes();
byte[] input = inputString.getBytes();

cipher.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), ivBytes));

byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
try
{
    cipher.doFinal(cipherText, outputLen);
}
catch (CryptoException ce)
{
    System.err.println(ce);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Note that the default padding mode of `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` is PKCS7/PKCS5.

Decryption is similar, but you would call `cipher.init(false, ...)` and pass in the ciphertext to `processBytes`.

Comment: What if i want to do encryption without any padding or with NoPadding. Its just that our server is ready with NoPadding, something like this "AES/ECB/NoPadding". Same thing done in J2ME and Android, not getting any help for doing AES encryption without any Padding in Blackberry.